# Is the phrase "la tiene muy caliente" (and others like it) considered good Spanish?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, expresiones

If I want to say

> **Feel his forehead.  Does it feel hot to you?**

am I using standard/good Spanish if I say:

> **Tócale la frente.  ¿La tiene muy caliente?**

I am primarily concerned with the phrase **"la tiene muy caliente."**  Is such a phrase considered grammatically correct?  Or is it more of a colloquialism?  If I were a doctor, would I ask about someone's body temperature in this way?

---

**¿Es la frase "la tiene muy caliente" (y otras similares) considerada buen español?**

Si quiero decir

> **Feel his forehead.  Does it feel hot to you?**

estoy usando español bien / español estándar si digo:

> **Tócale la frente.  ¿La tiene muy caliente?**

Me ocupo principalmente de la frase **"la tiene muy caliente".** ¿Es una frase como ésta gramaticalmente correcta?  ¿O es más de un coloquialismo?  Si fuera doctor, ¿preguntaría por la temperatura corporal de esta manera?

---

From comment: I'm interested in constructs that involve DIRECT OBJECT PRONOUN - TENER - ADJECTIVE, especially those that get translated into SUBJECT - TO BE - ADJECTIVE in English.

Comment: La frase está perfecta, incluso es habitual; pero eso sí, no olvides dar contexto (mencionar la frente). Ya sabes que "hot" tiene más significados, en inglés y en español.

Comment: @FGSUZ - (Overall I think the dangers of that word getting misunderstood are greater in Spanish.)

Comment: Just to understand the question better -- could you clarify the part of the title where you say "and others like it"?  What aspect of the sentence were you thinking of?  Thanks.

Comment: @aparente001 I was referring to constructs that involve DIRECT OBJECT PRONOUN - TENER - ADJECTIVE, especially those that get translated into SUBJECT - TO BE - ADJECTIVE in English.  I think it takes most native English speakers a while to get comfortable with the way this type of sentence can be constructed in Spanish, but discussion threads such as this help reinforce that it is, if nothing else, a perfectly natural way to provide a description of something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Tener* is used to indicate a state or condition of parts of the body in Spanish**.

**To have cold hands** is **tener las manos frías**. The verb tener is used to describe parts of the body that are hot, cold etc.

It's idiomatic to use *tener* in these situations. There is no other way to say it for the English usage of: to have a hot forehead, etc.

Un signo común de fiebre en los bebés es **tener la frente caliente**. Los pediatras recomiendan utilizar sólo termómetros digitales en niños. Los termómetros de mercurio no deben utilizarse porque presentan un riesgo de exposición y de intoxicación si se rompen.

[tener la frente caliente-site from Spain](http://www.farmaciadigame.es/blog/bebe-con-fiebre-que-hago.html)

Of course, in slang, if you don't say frente and just say la and are referring to the third person (él la tiene muy caliente it means: he has gotten/made her hot. But, really, that is not the case when the context shows you are talking about conditions or states of a person's body or its  parts.

Comment: Good answers from both you and @Mike, but the green check mark goes to you because it specifically addressed my question _and_ gave me broader context that allows me to apply this knowledge to other situations.  Excellent answer.  And thanks for the link.  I look forward to checking it out later.

Answer (score 3):

In Mexico this can be considered **ULTRA** politically incorrect, and thanks to the *[albur](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albur_(M%C3%A9xico))* culture you might get some jokes about it.

There's no problem on informal context, like with your family, but doctors and specialists will use the term "**temperatura**" and "**calentura**" which means "**temperature**" and "**fever,**" and they are expressed similarly to the way you would say "have an illness".

If his body heat is above normal: "tiene temperatura".
If it's too high: "tiene mucha temperatura".

And until you confirm that it's fever then you call it "tiene calentura".

---

Additionally:

If the fever gets too high is when is called "fiebre".

In México people will use "calentura" instead of "fiebre" as "fiebre" is considered a really bad disease, so from the taboo of fear it's reduce simply to "calentura".

Comment: Not in context. Only if guys are talking among themselves. Otherwise, in other contexts about comfort/discomfort of the body, it's the only way to translate: have cold hands, etc.

Comment: Correct, when you are inside context there's no problem and even doctors will ask for specific details.

Comment: Wow.  Well, all I can say is that I learn something new every time I visit the Spanish StackExchange ... even things I wasn't expecting to learn.  Not sure if this answer is worthy of the green check mark yet, but I voted you up just for expanding my knowledge in general.  Gracias ... en serio.

Answer (score 3):

*This is supplemental material.*

Some more examples of the pattern you are interested in:

> Tienes los pies muy sucios.  Te bañas antes de acostarte, por favor.
>
> Jorge tiene las manos muy grandes.

But this can be done with some other verbs as well, such as *dejar* and *traer*:

> Traes los zapatos muy sucios.
>
> ¿Me dejas la cocina bien arregladita, por favor?